# What's the number of threads created by below code and why?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I think the function will create threads until the resources will be exhausted, but i ran the code and I don't see the exhaustion of the resources..

```
DWORD WINAPI CreateThreads(LPVOID param)
{
    int n = *(int*)param;
    HANDLE* threads = (HANDLE*)malloc(n * sizeof(HANDLE));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        threads[i] = CreateThread(NULL,0, CreateThreads, &n, 0,NULL);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(threads[i], INFINITE);
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
      int n = 5;
      CreateThreads(&n);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking what `CreateThread` returns?

Comment: If you want more details: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/

Comment: If you really want to know how many threads are being created, you could have `CreateThreads()` atomically increment a counter variable upon entry, and atomically decrement the counter before exiting, and then you can display the current counter value periodically.

Answer (score 3):

Windows protects itself from this type of exhaustion. `CreateThread` would fail once you have reached the maximum allowed threads per process (Typically around 2000 threads for the Windows systems I had the pleasure of developing on)

You may have expected some resource to be exhausted first, but there are many resources that threads require, and the first one to exhaust itself would cause subsequent calls to `CreateThread` to fail. The primary two resources to exhaust from my experience are virtual memory due to the stack required by every new thread, and the limit of the number of threads the kernel can hold in the scheduler (the context switching mechanism).

Comment: And if i'll remove the WaitForSingleObject, i won't have resources exhaustion, right?

Comment: You would probably make things worse. Now, your program will end once it reaches the thread limit. If your threads terminate instead of waiting, newer threads may continue to get created forever.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper If you remove the WaitFor then some threads will finish and `n` inside each thread go out of scope, potentially before the next thread has copied it. So it's just gonna crash wildly if you do.

Comment: On second thought, without the wait, your main function will exit immediately and the program will terminate. try adding a long sleep in `main` and see what happens.

Comment: And FYI, you can replace the `WaitForSingleObject()` loop with a single `WaitForMultipleObjects()` call instead.